# Все инпуты которые не file и не submit

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Есть форма, с 10ти элементами, там типы инпутов все разные, и вот как то не могу понять, как выбрать инпуты все кроме типов file, и submit

```
var cntInp = $('form#lala').find('input[type!="file"]').length;
console.log(cntInp )// Выводит все инпуты с типами кроме file.
```

А как добавить в условие, еще что бы и отбросить инпуты с типом submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

inputs.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if(e.type == 'file' || e.type == 'submit') console.log(e.id, e);
});
```

```html
<input id='1' type='text'>
<input id='2' type='checkbox'>
<input id='3' type='radio'>
<input id='4' type='file'>
<input id='5' type='hidden'>
<input id='6' type='password'>
<input id='7' type='submit'>
<input id='8' type='button'>
<input id='9' type='range'>
<input id='10' type='number'>
```

<sub>jquery</sub>

```js
inputs = $('input').not(':input[type=file], :input[type=submit]');

inputs.each((i, e) => {
    console.log(e.id);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>

<input id='1' type='text'>
<input id='2' type='checkbox'>
<input id='3' type='radio'>
<input id='4' type='file'>
<input id='5' type='hidden'>
<input id='6' type='password'>
<input id='7' type='submit'>
<input id='8' type='button'>
<input id='9' type='range'>
<input id='10' type='number'>
```

Comment: Этой строчки хватит
inputs = $('input').not(':input[type=file], :input[type=submit]');
))

Comment: Я не ставил минус http://joxi.ru/zAN5dVZsNkpg29